# JPA JoinTable works with EclipseLink, but not with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, join

we have two tables (Source and Target) that are in a ManyToMany relationship. This relationship is defined by the table Traversal.

[image: Entity relations]

Below you can find the DDL to create these tables.

```
CREATE TABLE source (                                                                                                                                            
  source_name VARCHAR(50),                                                                                                                                       
  PRIMARY KEY (source_name)                                                                                                                                      
);                                                                                                                                                               

CREATE TABLE target (
  target_name VARCHAR(50), 
  position    FLOAT        NOT NULL,                                                                                                                             
  PRIMARY KEY (target_name)
);                                                                                                                                                                

CREATE TABLE traversal (                                                                                                                                         
  trav_id     INTEGER,                                                                                                                                           
  source_name VARCHAR(50),                                                                                                                                       
  target_name VARCHAR(50),                                                                                                                                       
  duration    FLOAT,                                                                                                                                             
  PRIMARY KEY (trav_id),                                                                                                                                         
  FOREIGN KEY (source_name) REFERENCES source(source_name),                                                                                                      
  FOREIGN KEY (target_name) REFERENCES target(target_name)                                                                                                       
);
```

And these are the entities we have defined:

Source:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Source implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "source_name")
  private String sourceName;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name= "source_name")
  private Set<Traversal> traversals= new HashSet<>();


  public Source() {
  }

  public Source(final String sourceName) {
    this.sourceName= sourceName;
  }


  public void addTraversal(final Traversal traversal) {
    this.traversals.add(traversal);
  }
}
```

Target:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Target implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "target_name")
  private String targetName;

  @Column(name = "position")
  private float position;


  public Target() {

  }

  public Target(final String targetName, final float position) {
    this.targetName= targetName;
    this.position= position;
  }

}
```

Traversal:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Traversal implements Serializable {

  @Id
//  @SequenceGenerator(name = "trav_seq_gen", sequenceName = "trav_id_seq", initialValue = 1)
//  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "trav_seq_gen")
  @Column(name = "trav_id")
  private long travId;

  @JoinColumn(name="target_name")
  private Target target;

  @Column(name = "duration")
  private float duration;

  public Traversal() {

  }

  public Traversal(final Target target) {
    this.target= target;
  }

  public Traversal(final Target target, final float duration) {
    this.target= target;
    this.duration= duration;
  }

  public Traversal(final long id, final Target target) {
    this.travId= id;
    this.target= target;
  }

  public Traversal(final long id, final Target target, final float duration) {
    this.travId= id;
    this.target= target;
    this.duration= duration;
  }
}
```

And this is some example code to insert some simple objects into the database:

```
import javax.persistence.*;


public class Test {

  private static final EntityManagerFactory emFactory= Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("rmtestPU");
  private static final EntityManager em= emFactory.createEntityManager();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // cleanup db
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Traversal tv").executeUpdate();
    em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Source s").executeUpdate();
    em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Target t").executeUpdate();
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    // populate db
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    final Target t1= new Target("t1", 2903.02f);
    em.persist(t1);
    final Target t2= new Target("t2", 289.28f);
    em.persist(t2);

    final Source s1= new Source("s1");
    em.persist(s1);
    final Source s2= new Source("s2");
    final Traversal tv_s2_t1= new Traversal(1555, t1, 2.2f);
    em.persist(tv_s2_t1);
    s2.addTraversal(tv_s2_t1);
    em.persist(s2);

    em.getTransaction().commit();

    em.close();
    emFactory.close();
  }

}
```

This code runs fine with EclipseLink. The tables are filled as expected.
However when using Hibernate, we get the error message:

```
Caused by: ERROR 42X14: 'TARGET' is not a column in table or VTI 'RM2.TRAVERSAL'.
```

What is going wrong here? Why is Hibernate trying to refence a column "TARGET"? The @JoinColumn annotation is explicitly setting it to "target_name".

Comment: Traversal.target must be annotated with ManyToOne.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes! You're absolutely right. How could I miss such a simple thing. Obviously EclipseLink tries to be smart enough to ignore that mistake.